# What's the correct place to send the issue for React translated docs?

Tags: reactjs, facebook, documentation

I have found an issue on https://ru.reactjs.org/ and I want to post it somewhere to be fixed by React team.

As far as it is not connected with React, but with a react website, I didn't find any repo on github is connected with React website.

My question is what is the correct place to post my issue for https://ru.reactjs.org/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By pressing the *Languages* icon at top nav, you have all translated docs list and their Github repositories: https://reactjs.org/languages

[image]

For the Russian language (translation issues), you can open an issue ticket / add a PR at the related [Github repo](https://github.com/reactjs/ru.reactjs.org/).

Comment: Thank you. Should I open an issue in a repo related to Russian language even if my issue is language independent?

Comment: If its not a translation issue, you should ask on Stackoverflow under `reactjs` tag (recommended, faster response) or open an issue on the main `facebook/react` repo